# Why GUI application not works perfectly?

Tags: gui

See these image -

[image]

[image]

The text are not shown correctly. But, terminal works well. Why? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: check to see that your font files are correct? be careful messing with system files.

Comment: Did you try to install a different language or skip the language installation on the install?

Comment: I try to install microsoft true type font long days ago and skip.

Comment: I've seen that before, some words only get shown with a few letters visible. I think it was display driver related. Did the MS TT font install cause it, or what else did you change recently that caused this? Maybe re-installing the default font packages might fix things, but nothing in the default Ubuntu repos should have broken any fonts... how did you try installing the MS fonts? Was Ubuntu 14.04 running 100% good for the last 3.5 years? Or consider trying a newer Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS is out.